# how list.sort() works when exclude one specific value?

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, comparator

I have a list

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("One");
names.add("Two");
names.add("Three");
names.add("Six");
names.add("Four");
names.add("Five");
```

I want this list to sort such that Six comes first, and then it should be in alphabetical order.

```
names.sort((x, y) -> {
            if (x.startsWith("S"))
                return -1;
            if (y.startsWith("S"))
                return 1; 
            return x.compareTo(y);
        });
```

This works fine. Why it is not working with only `x.startswith("S")` condition. Why I need to add condition for `y.startsWith("S")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't know in which order the `sort` algorithm will compare your `String`s. It might call `compare("Two","Six")` and it might call `compare("Six","Two")`. Therefore your `Comparator` must support both cases.

Besides, without checking `startsWith("S")` for both the first and second arguments, you are violating the `Comparator` contract, which requires that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))`.

BTW, it would be better to check `equals("Six")` instead of `startsWith("S")`. Otherwise your code will fail if your input will contain "Seven".

Answer (score 2):

collections.sort uses merge sort, the idea of the merge sort is to divide the list to single element list through stages and merging them back in these stages in ordered matter, so no guarantee your "six" will be the first element or second element in the comparison